# How do I prevent this invalid syntax error using reg.exe?

Tags: windows, cmd, registry

I'm trying to create a batch script to add multiple DWORD keys.

When testing the first one in an elevated cmd.exe window, I get the following error:

```bash
REG ADD HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Exchange\Forms Registry /v AlwaysUseMSOAuthForAutoDiscover /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

ERROR: Invalid syntax.
```

Keys to add:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Exchange\Forms Registry

AlwaysUseMSOAuthForAutoDiscover Value: 1


HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover

ExcludeHttpsRootDomain Value: 1

ExcludeHttpsAutoDiscoverDomain Value: 1

ExcludeScpLookup Value: 1

ExcludeSrvRecord Value: 1

ExcludeLastKnownGoodURL Value: 1
```

I have tried this with other key locations (HKLM) and it works for me.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Put quotes around the key name

Comment: Making modifications within subkeys of a users root key whilst running as that user, does not require elevation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, keys, values, and data containing spaces, and other potentially poison characters, should be enclosed within doublequotes.

Example:

```bash
C:\Users\MWhaley>%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Exchange\Forms Registry" /V AlwaysUseMSOAuthForAutoDiscover /T REG_DWORD /V 1 /F 1>NUL

C:\Users\MWhaley>For %G In (HttpsRootDomain HttpsAutoDiscoverDomain ScpLookup SrvRecord LastKnownGoodURL) Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover /V Exclude%G /T REG_DWORD /V 1 /F 1>NUL
```